# Cmake error when installing

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, cmake

Estoy tratando de probar un programa hecho sólo para Linux, asi que instalé Ubuntu en VirtualBox. Cuando trato de compilarlo tira este error:

> Cmake error at CmakeLists.txt
>
> The Cmake_C Compiler.
>
> Path_to_emsdk/upstream/emscripten/emcc
>
> is not a full path and was not found in path
>
> Tell Cmake where to find the compiler by setting either the enviroment
> variable "CC" or the Cmake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full
> path to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.

Estuve leyendo y probé algunas soluciones sin resultado, como hacer

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install -y build-essential

y otros similares

> sudo apt-get install g++

pero sigue tirando el mismo error. Alguna idea de qué puede ser?

Comment: Encontré un par de guías para instalar CMake, una [oficial](https://cmake.org/install/) y [esta otra para Ubuntu 20.04 LTS](https://vitux.com/how-to-install-cmake-on-ubuntu/) desde "Ubuntu Software" o desde terminal.

Comment: @triby ya encontré el error, hay que cambiar en un archivo de la aplicación llamado "Cmake cache" la entrada "CMAKE_C_COMPILER" , en lugar de ser   =/usr/bing/clang++ es =/usr/bin/clang++